# Azure alert to notify when a vm is stopped

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-alerts

I'd like to get a notification whenever a VM is stopped. Currently I've done it (for one VM only) using a hearbeat log alert to check every 10 min but that I want it to implemented for the whole subscription (100+ vms) I cannot do it sincgle alert for each vm due to cost.
After google it I found that there is a signal alert called Power Off Virtual Machine (Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines) that should fulfill the requirement but after set the alert and stopping a VM nothing is being received. Is there any missing step maybe ?
PS. I'm using VM Insights + new Azure Monitor Agent.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and dint get the email notification when the VM was stopped for*** **`Power Off Virtual Machine`** ***operation***:

[image]

**To receive an alert to notify when the VM is stopped, please try the below:**

Make sure to select the scope for the whole subscription:

[image: stopp]

Please **note** that, to receive an alert when the VM is stopped, make sure to select **`Deallocate Virtual Machine`** operation:

[image]

While creating the Action Group, select the **`Email`** option:

[image]

**When I VM stopped, I got the email notification successfully like below:**

[image]

[image]

***The Alert rule is successfully fired in the Monitor like below:***

[image]