# how to get Azure VM last reboot using azure resource graph

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-graph

I'm using azure resource graph to create dashboard and need the VM last reboot or Power-Off date.
Need your helps please.
Thank you

Comment: I got it using Event Table in log analytics workspace but i look for the same information in azure resource graph...to use the same service...

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

Graph query:

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| summarize count() by PowerState = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code)
```

Checked the powerstate :
[image]

Tried below query :

```
resources
| where type has 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions' 
| where name has 'MicrosoftMonitoringAgent' or name has 'AzureMonitorWindowsAgent' 
| extend AzureVM = extract('virtualMachines/(.*)/extensions',1,id), ArcVM = extract('machines/(.*)/extensions',1,id)
|summarize count() by name=tolower(AzureVM), ArcVM=tolower(ArcVM), subscriptionId, resourceGroup,  AgentType=name
| extend hasBoth = iff(count_ > 0, 'Yes', 'No') 
| join 
 ( 
    resources
    | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
    | project name, properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus,
                    properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code,
                    created_ = properties.timeCreated
    | order by name desc
 ) on name
```

where i got created time of azure vm running and deallocation time.

[image]

If you want the alert when the vm stpped you can check this : [azureportal - Azure alert to notify when a vm is stopped - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200229/azure-alert-to-notify-when-a-vm-is-stopped)

**Reference:**  [resource-graph-samples | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: Thanks @kavya but there is no deallocation time in your query.
the time displayed is the time of the VM creation